# Pyspark - Divide dataframes after crosstab

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, crosstab

I have two dataframes that come from doing a crosstab, and I want to divide one by the other in pyspark. The idea is that I have two frequency dataframes and I want to get a percentage. How can this be done?

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct
a = joined_df.crosstab("B", "C")
b = joined_df.withColumn("AB", struct("A", "B")).crosstab("AB", "C")

print("Check that cross tabs have same number of rows: ", a.count(), b.count())
```

I wanna do

```python
c = a/b
```

Comment: @zero323 do you know?

Comment: zero323 hasn't logged on to SO since October 2017. In any case, it would be easier to answer your question with a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples). However, based on what I think you're asking, the answer is going to be no because you can't do element wise math operations on spark dataframes the way you can with pandas.